# Python-mock: how to test if super() was called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following structure:

```
class A(Object):
    def method(self):
        return 'a'

class B(A):
   def __init__(self, test):
       self.test = test

   def method(self):
        if self.test:
           return super(A, self).method(self)
        else:
           return 'b'
```

What I want to do is write a test-case which would test that if self.test is true then the super function was called and class A's method function was called.

How I can achieve this? What should I mock?

Advanced Q: What about when Class A and B are in a separate module, and they have the same name.
So instead of class B I would write: class A(module1.A):
does that change the mocking?

Comment: couldn't you patch `A.method`? ... `with mock.patch.object(A, 'method'): ...`  You shouldn't care _how_ it got called (e.g. via super or via some other means...) What matters is _that_ it got called.

Comment: Your test should only care that `method` returns `'a'` or `'b'`. How the method achieved this is not something your test should care about. If, in the future, you wanted to refactor `B.method()` and it no longer uses `super()`, your method is no less valid if it still behaves the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you don't mock calls to external classes, wouldn't that be a sort of integration test? I had the feeling (from Sandi Metz's talks) that what you say is only true when dealing with calls to private methods (do not mock them, just assert the final public side-effects or return values). However, mocking calls to internal public methods does indeed create a dependency on the implementation, so I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just checked Metz's talk again and I think I was partially wrong. In the case of query messages, we're only interested in what the method returns at the end (regardless of what it calls internally). If the message is not a query but a command (it changes some state) we're interested in asserting the public side effects on the instance, or to mock calls to external instances. But I feel like I'm still missing something. Should we mock calls to internal public methods, since we're going to unit-test them separately? Link to the talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M

Comment: @KurtBourbaki: the edges of what makes up a unit are not fixed, but generally speaking: if you can't reuse that method in a different context, it is not a distinct unit. Here `B().method()` is not reusable outside of the context of `B()`, so all of `B` is part of the unit.

Comment: @KurtBourbaki: and in practical day to day work: you can always, later on, decide that a unit-under-test needs to be broken down into smaller units if that helps increase confidence or if regressions have been found that you want to test for. Testing is a tool, not the end goal, and it serves software development velocity. Don't let it bog you down!

Comment: @MartijnPieters that of "reusability" is a very useful suggestion, thank you. Also, your last recommendation to use testing as a tool is definitely worth noting, as I find that being too strict on the process can make me lose focus on the end goal at times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [@MartijnPieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) points out, testing that super is called is typically a test of an implementation detail, rather than a test of a contract. Nonetheless, testing the specific implementation may still be desirable -- or the parent class may have a contract requiring the call to super. To test that super is called, use a mock, as mentioned by [@mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson). The answer in detail:

```
import mock, unittest

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("A.method")
    def test_super_method(self, mock_super):
        B(True).method()
        self.assertTrue(mock_super.called)

    @mock.patch("A.method")
    def test_super_method(self, mock_super):
        B(False).method()
        self.assertFalse(mock_super.called)
```

You'll need to specify the full namespace in the patch. E.g., `@mock.patch("module.submodule.A.method")`. This can be done for any method in A, including `__init__`; syntax is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

To build off of @Malina's excellent answer, if you can't patch the method on module A (e.g. A is in a third party library, part of a nasty legacy system, dynamically created at runtime, etc.) you can still test this functionality by creating another method on class B explicitly for the purpose of testing.

*Revised Class `B`*

```py
import A

class B(A):
   def __init__(self, test):
       self.test = test

   def method(self):
        if self.test:
           self._delegate_to_A()  # Move the super call to a separate method
        else:
           return 'b'
   
   def _delegate_to_A(self)
       return super(A, self).method(self)
```

*Revised Test Code for Class `B`*

```py
import mock, unittest

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):

    # Patch B's `delegate` method instead of A
    @mock.patch("B._delegate_to_A")
    def test_super_method(self, mock_super):
        B(True).method()
        self.assertTrue(mock_super.called)

    @mock.patch("B._delegate_to_A")
    def test_super_method(self, mock_super):
        B(False).method()
        self.assertFalse(mock_super.called)
```