# Test if super() was called during initialization gives AttributeError

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to test if in the following scenario the init routine of the Base class is called during the initialization of the Derived class:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super(Derived, self).__init__(a)
```

I used [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142601/python-mock-how-to-test-if-super-was-called) and this test works fine:

```
@mock.patch("mocktest.Base.__init__")
def test_calls_init_routine_of_base(mock_super_init):
    Derived(1)
    assert mock_super_init.called
```

However, if the Derived class does something with the attribute `a` after `super(Derived, self).__init(a)`, e.g. if I put a `print(self.a)` right after the call to super(), then the test throws an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'Derived' object has no attribute 'a'
```

How can I prevent this? Are there other/better ways to realize this test in this situation?

Comment: You generally do not mock out parent `__init__` methods. They are very much part of the unit-under-test.

Comment: OK, thanks for the comment. I'm rather unexperienced in this area, so what would you recommend?

Comment: Stick to mocking out anything *outside* the unit-under-test, where convenient. You are testing your unit, not if, say, a socket works, or if the HTML parser works, or another service in your code base. Mock those out. That's a rather broad subject to discuss in comments, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, never do this kind of mock... If you want to test super call try to find a super behavior that you can check.

If you don't find any other way or you have some mysterious reasons to check it (I did it in the past but I cannot remember why... maybe I did the wrong thing) you can just wrap it:

```
@mock.patch("mocktest.Base.__init__", wraps=mocktest.Base.__init__)
def test_calls_init_routine_of_base(mock_super_init):
    Derived(1)
    assert mock_super_init.called
```

---

If you really need to avoid a super call (for instance you derive from something that start a thread or access to some remote resource) you should patch the attributes that you need too:

```
@mock.patch("mocktest.Base.a", create=True)
@mock.patch("mocktest.Base.__init__")
def test_calls_init_routine_of_base(mock_super_init):
    Derived(1)
```